# Using the same type discriminator for superclass and subclass in OpenJPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I'm trying to replicate a behavior of hibernate using OpenJPA, i tried something like:

SuperClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class A{...
```

SubClass:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class B extends A{..
```

that causes the exception indicting that two class cannot have the same discriminator.

Is there a solution for this by using only Annotations?

Comment: the abstract class shouldn't need a "value"

Comment: Its not abstruct now.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're saying is that you want to persist an object of type `A` and an object of type `B` and when they are retrieved then they are BOTH instantiated as instances of type `A`? so the `B` will no longer be a `B`!!

I can't find any situation where that would be considered a *good idea*. Any JPA implementation that imposes that all concrete types have a different discriminator value is doing the right thing. Consequently we can conclude that `OpenJPA` behaviour is as it should be, and "working around it" is a bad idea.

Comment: I understand that this is a bad design although it worked with hibernate. I just trying to migrate it to openjpa, while there is a lot of business logic dependencies that can break if i will change that desgin, which is too expensive. I need two entites that associated with the same table, a Subclass and superclass, with the same type discriminator.